# jQuery .ready/resize does not work on iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad

Why don't the ready/resize events work on the iPad? They work on the computer but not on the iPad. Does someone knows what I did wrong?

```
jQuery(document).on('ready', function() {
    jQuery(window).on('resize', function() {
        /* Tablet Portrait size to standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
        if (jQuery(window).width() < 960 && jQuery(window).width() > 768) {
           //change the attributes from the div #home_content (first parameter: the attribute, what it needs to be)
           jQuery('#home_content').attr('class','sixteen columns');
           jQuery('#slider').attr('class','sixteen columns');
        }
        else{
            jQuery('#home_content').attr('class','nine columns');
            jQuery('#slider').attr('class','nine columns');
        }

        /* Mobile Landscape Size to Tablet Portrait (devices and browsers) */
        if(jQuery(window).width() < 767 && jQuery(window).width() > 480) {
            //code
        }
        else{

        }

        /* Mobile Landscape Size to Tablet Portrait (devices and browsers) */
        if(jQuery(window).width() < 479) {
            //code
        }   
        else{

        }
    }).trigger('resize'); // Trigger resize handlers.       
});//ready
```

Comment: Do you mean they are not working, or not firing? If you put an `alert('foo')` in there does it pop up?

Comment: On the computer it does pop up but not on the iPad

Comment: Did you put the alert in the document ready or the resize? Are both of them not firing or just one?

Comment: You can also use

window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function () {
// Your code here
};

Comment: @brso05, your edit matched "doesn't" to "events" ("Why doesn't the ready/resize events work"), which is incorrect. My edit was valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
// Checks to see if the platform is strictly equal to iPad:
if (navigator.platform === 'iPad') {
    window.onorientationchange = function() {

        var orientation = window.orientation;

        // Look at the value of window.orientation:
        if (orientation === 0) {
            // iPad is in Portrait mode.

        } else if (orientation === 90) {
            // iPad is in Landscape mode. The screen is turned to the left.

        } else if (orientation === -90) {
            // iPad is in Landscape mode. The screen is turned to the right.

        } else if (orientation === 180) {
            // Upside down portrait.

        }
    }
}​
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to capture the orientation of the iPad, you should use:

```
window.onorientationchange = function(e) { /* your code */ };
```

rather than the windows resize event.

Comment: How should I include that in my code? like this?: jQuery(window).onorientationchange() < 960 etc?

Answer (score 1):

Please check Following

```
$(window).resize(function() {

alert("Window size changed");

});
```

To access height and width you can use

```
$(window).width();

$(window).height();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `jQuery(document).ready(function(){ alert('booya!') })`;

and put your code in that function if you get an alert. Also visit the page in Chrome and check for Javascript errors by bringing up the built-in console in Developer Tools.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
instead of jQuery(window).width() I used jQuery(document).width() and now my my script works hopefully on *every* device :) 
Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

It does work now,

My code didnt work because I uesed window.width() which doesnt work on the iPad, I changed it to document.width and now it works. :)

Answer (score -1):

iPads, along with some other touch devices, do not fire the **resize** event as frequently as desktop browsers. This can result in the code not being executed as expected. To resolve this issue, you can try using the **orientationchange** event instead of the **resize** event. This event is fired on touch devices when the orientation of the device changes.

Here's the updated code:

```
jQuery(document).on('ready', function() {
    jQuery(window).on('orientationchange', function() {
        /* Tablet Portrait size to standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
        if (jQuery(window).width() < 960 && jQuery(window).width() > 768) {
           //change the attributes from the div #home_content (first parameter: the attribute, what it needs to be)
           jQuery('#home_content').attr('class','sixteen columns');
           jQuery('#slider').attr('class','sixteen columns');
        }
        else{
            jQuery('#home_content').attr('class','nine columns');
            jQuery('#slider').attr('class','nine columns');
        }

        /* Mobile Landscape Size to Tablet Portrait (devices and browsers) */
        if(jQuery(window).width() < 767 && jQuery(window).width() > 480) {
            //code
        }
        else{

        }

        /* Mobile Landscape Size to Tablet Portrait (devices and browsers) */
        if(jQuery(window).width() < 479) {
            //code
        }   
        else{

        }
    }).trigger('orientationchange'); // Trigger orientationchange handlers.       
});//ready
```