# How to handle the resize event and the iPad keyboard in browser application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, keyboard-events

I work with a browser application, built in javascript/jQuery, that opens up a popover/dialog when pressing a certain button. The popover is aligned to that button. If we resize the browser window we want the popover to close, so we listen to the resize event and close the popover. But the problem is when we access the application in a browser in an iPad. If we enter something in one of the input fields inside the popover, and then chooses to hide the keyboard by pressing the "hide keyboard" button, a resize event occures and the popover is closed. And we do not want it to close in this case.

Does anyone has an idea of how we can solve this? Can we capture that the keyboard is closed? I have only found notifications used in Apps, not in browser web sites. Or can we listen to another event to close the popover when the browser window is resized?

Comment: Can you please share some code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solutions for your project.

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange', function(event) {
  if (window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90 || window.orientation == 270) {
    // When orientation is 90 / -90 / 270 degrees
  } else {
    // When orientation is other degrees
  }
});
```

Also you can look these links below.

[jQuery .ready/resize does not work on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510530/jquery-ready-resize-does-not-work-on-ipad)

[how to resize / rezoom webpage in ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557971/how-to-resize-rezoom-webpage-in-ipad)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gesturechange event then test against firing that event since it sounds like it needs to be ignored for a few special cases.

```
 $.bind("gesturechange", function(event) {
     // event.originalEvent.scale;
 });
```